# Regex not matching c#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Hi I am using a regex to match UK phone numbers which looks like below:

```
/^\(?0( *\d\)?){9,10}$/
```

http://regexr.com/39icf

I've tried testing the regex above but receive no matches for the numbers input which look valid to me.

Is my regex correct?

Comment: what do you expect to match , add a few examples

Comment: On regexr, have you turned on the "multiline" and "gloabal" flags?

Comment: The regex matches my home phone number fine. Can you provide an example that you think should match but does not.

Comment: I'd be very careful trying to use RegEx for phone numbers, there's so many formats that you may miss. How about the difference between `(01234)567890`, `(01234) 567890`, `+44(0)1234 567890`, `+441234567890`, etc.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah i understand what you mean. What would you recommend to validate them?

Comment: I'm confused, what does this have to do with [tag:c#]? Generally I'd write off the tag and edit it out, but I see you included it in the title as well. Is it actually relevant in a way I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working correct but you forget to select these checkboxes:

[image]